# firebase deployment error with babel register

Tags: function, firebase, google-cloud-functions, babeljs, firebase-cli

I'm currently trying to deploy a web application using Firebase Cloud Functions

Everything works fine locally with `firebase serve`. But when I use `firebase deploy`, I got the following error on the firebase console :

```
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/user_code/node_modules/.cache'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:932:18)
    at sync (/user_code/node_modules/@babel/register/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at sync (/user_code/node_modules/@babel/register/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at sync (/user_code/node_modules/@babel/register/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at save (/user_code/node_modules/@babel/register/lib/cache.js:50:20)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

I'm afraid not to be able to use babel-register on the production environment because of the read-only property of the environment. Do you have any idea to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I found out that you can set the default directory where you want to create a folder, I had this same issue when deploying to firebase functions also, but read about this issue happening with heroku, where you only have write permissions to a `tmp` folder
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register#babel-cache-path